# C OS X Read Directory Contents into String Array

Tags: c, macos, directory, osx-mavericks

I am trying to get the contents of a directory. Ideally, I would like to store them in a string array. Is there a way to do this in c other than opening the directory, iterating through its contents, and populating an array as it goes?

I am working on a system running OS X 10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain an allocated directory listing with the POSIX [scandir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alphasort.html) function, which takes a path and optional filtering and sorting callbacks, and returns an array of `dirent` structures. OS X also provides [an equivalent function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/scandir.3.html) which takes blocks rather than callbacks for sorting and filtering.

```
int scandir(const char *dirname, struct dirent ***namelist,
            int (*select)(const struct dirent *),
            int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

Just retrieving an unsorted list of entries is very straightforward:

```
int num_entries;
struct dirent **entries = NULL;

num_entries = scandir("/", &entries, NULL, NULL);

for(int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
    puts(entries[i]->d_name);

//entries is ours to free
for(int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
    free(entries[i]);
free(entries);
```

POSIX also provides a pre-made sorting function to use with scandir for alphabetical ordering. To use it, just pass `alphasort` as the last argument.

Be careful of scandir returning an error (-1). The above code is structured in such a way that an explicit check isn't necessary, but that may not be possible in more elaborate uses.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to run using system libc call and fopen.

Here is the sample code, take care of all the array lengths, there is NO validation done here.
    #include
    #include
    #include

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     char cmd[254] = "ls ";
     char arr[1024];
     char line[254];
     FILE *fp;
     if(argc < 2) return -1;
     if(argv[1]) strcat(cmd, argv[1]);
      strcat(cmd, " > /tmp/out");
     system(cmd);

     fp = fopen("/tmp/out", "r");
     if(!fp){
       perror("");
       return fprintf(stderr, "could not open /tmp/out!\n");
     }
     while(fgets(line, 254, fp) != NULL) {
        strcat(arr, line);
     }
     printf("%s\n", arr);
     return 0;
}
```